Why can I not drill down a model to get to a field?
I have this contestant model:
class Contestant(models.Model):
    GENDERS = [
        ("male", "Male"),
        ("female", "Female")
    ]
    EYE_COLORS = [
        ("brown", "Brown"),
        ("blue", "Blue"),
        ("green", "Green"),
        ("hazel", "Hazel"),
        ("amber", "Amber"),
        ("gray", "Gray")
    ]
    HAIR_COLORS = [
        ("black", "Black"),
        ("brown", "Brown"),
        ("blonde", "Blonde"),
        ("red", "Red"),
        ("gray", "Gray"),
        ("white", "White"),
        ("pink", "Pink"),
        ("purple", "Purple"),
        ("green", "Green"),
        ("orange", "Orange")
    ]
    main_photo = models.FileField(upload_to='main_image/')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=GENDERS)
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(120)])
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(1500)])
    eye_color = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=EYE_COLORS)
    hair_color = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=HAIR_COLORS)
    city = models.OneToOneField(City, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="contestant")
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="contestant_profile")

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="updated at")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "contestant"
        verbose_name_plural = "contestants"
        db_table = "contestants"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"contestant {self.user}"

and I want people to vote on the contestant. Here is the votes model:
class ContestantVote(models.Model):
    contestant = models.ForeignKey(Contestant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10)])
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="votes")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="updated at")

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("contestant", "user"),)
        verbose_name = "vote"
        verbose_name_plural = "votes"
        db_table = "votes"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if ContestantVote.objects.filter(contestant=self.contestant, user=self.user).exists():
            raise ValidationError(f'User {self.user} has already voted for contestant {self.contestant}.')

        if self.score == 10:
            existing_vote = ContestantVote.objects.filter(
                user=self.user,
                contestant__gender=self.contestant.gender,
                score=10
            ).exists()
            if existing_vote:
                raise ValidationError(f'User {self.user} has already given a score of 10 to a {self.contestant.gender} contestant.')
        
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Vote for {self.contestant} by {self.user}"

I am trying to prevent a user from giving two contestants of the same gender the same top mark which is 10 but I keep on running into the same error of the field doesn't exist on the vote but I am trying to check the field on a related field using the double underscore format.
Here is the error:
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: ContestantVote has no field named 'contestant__gender'

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here please?

Please post the full traceback so it's clear where this error originates.

Would be helpful to have complete error traceback as @deceze mention and I would suggest to start from checking model for a proper migratons. Another point to start debug from performing django shell query to the field causes an exception.

The error speaks for itself. The field does not exist...for sure you forgot to apply changes to the database by running makemigrations and migrate. Besides that, your code works as expected.

Looks like a missing/unapplied migrations issue.
Either way any answer trying to give you a reason won't be helpful for you.
Here is what you should do:

create unittests
create unittests
create unittests

There are a lot of other things you could improve here that won't be helpful for you at this stage, but unittests are defenitely the first step.
Add a test for missing migrations (lot's of links online for this).
After you add unittests:

go back to code where tests pass
add some code you want
test it untill it passes
back to step 2.


also please don't write stuff in the save method of a model :( .
